# How to run an anonymous function in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
(sub {
print 1;
})();



sub {
print 1;
}();
```

I tried various ways, all are wrong...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`(sub { ... })` will give you the pointer to the function so you must call by reference.

`(sub { print "Hello world\n" })->();`

The other easy method, as pointed out by [Blagovest Buyukliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265804/blagovest-buyukliev) would be to dereference the function pointer and call that using the `{ }` operators

`&{ sub { print "Hello World" }}();`

Comment: That should be `&{ sub { print "Hello World" }}()`. Without the parens, it's a very special call.

Comment: @ikegami: what do you mean by 'a very special call'? Why can't you leave the parentheses out?

Comment: @Medlock Perlman, `&foo` is similar to `&foo(@_)`, except any modification to the `@_` affects the parents `@_` too.

Answer (score 31):

Yay, I didn't expect you folks to come up with that much possibilities. But you're right, this is perl and [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it): +1 for creativitiy!

But to be honest, I use hardly another form than the following:

## The Basic Syntax

```perl
my $greet = sub {
    my ( $name ) = @_;
    print "Hello $name\n";
};

# ...

$greet->( 'asker' )
```

It's pretty straight forward: `sub {}` returns a reference to a sub routine, which you can store and pass around like any other scalar. You can than call it by dereferencing. There is also a second syntax to dereference: `&{ $sub }( 'asker' )`, but I personally prefer the arrow syntax, because I find it more readable and it pretty much aligns with dereferencing hashes `$hash->{ $key }` and arrays `$array->[ $index ]`. More information on references can be found in [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

I think the other given examples are a bit advanced, but why not have a look at them:

## Goto

```
sub bar {goto $foo};
bar;
```

Rarely seen and much feared these days. But at least it's a `goto &function`, which is considered less harmful than it's crooked friends: `goto LABEL` or `goto EXPRESSION` ( they are deprecated since 5.12 and raise a warning ). There are actually some circumstances, when you want to use that form, because this is not a usual function call. The calling function ( `bar` in the given example ) will not appear in the callling stack. And you don't pass your parameters, but the current `@_` will be used. Have a look at this:

```
use Carp qw( cluck );

my $cluck = sub {
    my ( $message ) = @_;
    cluck $message . "\n";
};


sub invisible {
    @_ = ( 'fake' );
    goto $cluck;
}

invisible( 'real' );
```

Output:

```
fake at bar.pl line 5
    main::__ANON__('fake') called at bar.pl line 14
```

And there is no hint of an invisible function in the stack trace. More info on goto in [perldoc -f goto](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html).

## Method Calls

```
''->$foo;
# or
undef->$foo;
```

If you call a method on an object, the first parameter passed to that method will be the invocant ( usually an instance or the class name ). Did i already say that [TIMTOWTCallAFunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)?

```
# this is just a normal named sub
sub ask {
    my ( $name, $question ) = @_;
    print "$question, $name?\n";
};

my $ask = \&ask; # lets take a reference to that sub 

my $question = "What's up";

'asker'->ask( $question ); # 1: doesn't work

my $meth_name = 'ask';
'asker'->$meth_name( $question ); # 2: doesn't work either

'asker'->$ask( $question ); # 1: this works
```

In the snippet above are two calls, which won't work, because perl will try to find a method called `ask` in package `asker` ( actually it would work if that code was in the said package ). But the third one succeeds, because you already give perl the right method and it doesn't need to search for it. As always: more info in the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) I can't find any reason right now, to excuse this in production code.

## Conclusion

Originally I didn't intend to write that much, but I think it's important to have the common solution at the beginning of an answer and some explanations to the unusual constructs. I admit to be kind of selfish here: Every one of us could end up maintaining someones code, who found this question and just copied the topmost example.

Comment: +1 for courage; whenever I donate my time to write answers like this, I get reamed by the trucks with downvotes containing ...way too long.. or  ..nobody wants to spend this much time to read this... so, I'll put in this +1 just in case you get hit by a truck. (and anyone else who did so)

Comment: @osirisgothra thanks for the nice words. the answer is nearly four years old - and no trucks so far :-D

Comment: Programmers who can't be bothered to read are lazy in the bad way, not the good way. They're basically not far from the "do my [home]work for me so I can go [to the beach | home early]" crowd.

Comment: By the way though... `goto` is not deprecated, apart from for _jumping into a construct_. This _is_ deprecated and _will_ issue a warning.  
Cf. `perldoc -f goto` or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html

Answer (score 12):

There is not much need in Perl to call an anonymous subroutine where it is defined.  In general you can achieve any type of scoping you need with bare blocks.  The one use case that comes to mind is to create an aliased array:

```
my $alias = sub {\@_}->(my ($x, $y, $z));

$x = $z = 0;
$y = 1;

print "@$alias"; # '0 1 0'
```

Otherwise, you would usually store an anonymous subroutine in a variable or data structure.  The following calling styles work with both a variable and a `sub {...}` declaration:

```
dereference arrow:  sub {...}->(args)  or  $code->(args)

dereference sigil:  &{sub {...}}(args) or &$code(args)
```

if you have the coderef in a scalar, you can also use it as a method on regular and blessed values.

```
my $method = sub {...};

$obj->$method           # same as $method->($obj)
$obj->$method(...)      # $method->($obj, ...)

[1, 2, 3]->$method      # $method->([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]->$method(...) # $method->([1, 2, 3], ...)
```

Comment: `sub{}->()`, `do{}` and `{}` all have different properties. I'd put `sub{}->()` closer to `do{}`, not `{}`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm endlessly amused by finding ways to call anonymous functions:

```
$foo = sub {say 1};

sub bar {goto $foo};
bar;

''->$foo; # technically a method, along with the lovely:

undef->$foo;

() = sort $foo 1,1; # if you have only two arguments
```

and, of course, the obvious:

```
&$foo();
$foo->();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need arrow operator:

```
(sub { print 1;})->();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not even need an anonymous function if you want to run a block of code and there is zero or one input. You can use `map` instead.

Just for the side effect:

```
map { print 1 } 1;
```

Transform data, take care to assign to a list:

```
my ($data) = map { $_ * $_ } 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# ------------------------------------------------------
# perl: filter array using given function
# ------------------------------------------------------
sub filter {
   my ($arr1, $func) = @_;
   my @arr2=();
   foreach ( @{$arr1} ) {
        push ( @arr2, $_ ) if $func->( $_ );
   };
   return @arr2;
}

# ------------------------------------------------------
# get files from dir
# ------------------------------------------------------
sub getFiles{
 my ($p) = @_;
 opendir my $dir, $p  or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
 my @files=readdir $dir;
 closedir $dir;
 #return files and directories that not ignored but not links
 return filter \@files, (sub { my $f = $p.(shift);return ((-f $f) || (-d $f)) && (! -l $f) } ); 
}
```