# Perl return if statement variable

Tags: perl, if-statement

How can i do something like that:
I want return IP server from if statment, where i sign if to variable. It is possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#

use warnings;
use strict;

my $variable1 = "10.12.1.1";
my $variable2 = "10.12.1.2";

my $string = $ARGV[0];

my $serveris=>(if ($string =~ m/^[abcdefghijklm]/) {
            print " $variable1 \n"
} else {
            print " $variable2 \n"
})


print $serveris
```

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to do that are to use the ternary operator [`?:`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator), or move the assignment into the body of the `if`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $variable1 = "10.12.1.1";
my $variable2 = "10.12.1.2";

my $string = "x";

my $serveris =
    $string =~ m/^[abcdefghijklm]/
    ? $variable1 : $variable2;
# -- OR --
my $serveris;
if ($string =~ m/^[abcdefghijklm]/) {
    $serveris = $variable1;
} else {
    $serveris = $variable2;
}

print " $serveris \n"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of lambda functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $variable1 = "10.12.1.1";
my $variable2 = "10.12.1.2";

my $string = $ARGV[0];

my $serveris = sub {
    my ( $string ) = @_;
    if ($string =~ m/^[abcdefghijklm]/) {
            return " $variable1 \n"
    } else {
            return " $variable2 \n"
    }

};

print $serveris->($string)
```

References: [How to run an anonymous function in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343526/how-to-run-an-anonymous-function-in-perl)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option for your example code is to use the ternary operator:

```
my $serveris = $string =~ m/^[abcdefghijklm]/
             ? $variable1
             : $variable2;
```

However, if things are more complicated, nested ternary operators can cause some confusion.  To maintain the structure of your `if/else` statements, use a `do` block.  `do` returns the result of the last statement evaluated in the block as its value.

```
my $serveris = do {
    if ($string =~ m/^[abcdefghijklm]/) {
        $variable1;
    } else {
        $variable2;
    }
};
```